# What is best practice for importing internal modules to another subdirectory in python?

Tags: python, architecture, environment

I currently have a project folder structured as this

```
Project/ 
    main.py
    .gitignore
    .env
    requirements.txt
    reports/
        report1.py
        report2.py
    utils/
        __init__.py
        support_functions.py
```

For this program, I am not trying to run a main function. I have several reports that I run once a week/month, and just run them straight from its file.
I was having a lot of trouble importing the functions from the utils module - however, I did find a workaround on stack overflow which is essentially adding the folder to the path

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/Project/utils')
import support_functions
```

However, I don't love this workaround as it uses an absolute path, and wouldn't work when I am switching computers/os/enviroments.
So my main question is how is this handled on larger projects? I have run into a couple other scenarios where I want to do this, even when I am using the "correct" structure and running a main function.

1. A test folder, which would import functions from another module for testing
2. Any situation when I want to import a function or class from another internal module
3. Is this just not commonly done in python? Am I missing something obvious regarding architecture?

Comment: You should package your package and then install it.

Answer (score 0):

I FINALLY found the answer.

Solution: Edit your settings.json with

```
"terminal.integrated.env.osx": {"PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}"}
```

Note - osx will need to be changed to "linux" or "windows" on those operating systems.

Documentation on the issue and solutions can be found [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) under the "Use of the PYTHONPATH variable" section.

There are alternative solutions of changing your PYTHONPATH by setting it in your .env, and then pointing to that in settings.json, however, neither worked for me. Solution ended up being to have VScode point the PYTHONPPATH to the current working directory, something that is done automatically in Pycharm.